# Pickling objects

Tags: python, wxpython, pickle

I need to pickle object [wxpython frame object] and send it as a prameter to this function apply_async on multiproccessing pool module 
could someone provide me an example how can I do it 
I tried the following and get an error message :

```
myfile = file(r"C:\binary.dat", "w")
pickle.dump(self, myfile)
myfile.close()


self.my_pool.apply_async(fun,[i,myfile])

def fun(i,self_object):
    window = pickle.load(self_oject)
    wx.CallAfter(window.LogData, msg)
```

could someone tell me what could be the problem

If the error give some indicator below the last error message i get:
 File "C:\Python26\lib\copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.**name**
TypeError: can't pickle PySwigObject objects

Comment: i don't know enought about pickling but the errormessage hould be helpful for other helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not serialize a widget for use in another process. I guess you want to change the GUI content from another process that is started by the `multiprocessing` module. In that case, you should define a callback function in the parent process that gets called when the result of the sub-process is ready. Therefore you can use the "callback" parameter of [`apply_async`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async).

Something like:

```
def fun(i):
    # do something in this sub-process and then return a log message
    return "finished doing something"

def cb(resultFromFun):
    wx.CallAfter(window.LogData, resultFromFun)

my_pool.apply_async(fun, [i], callback = cb)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that wxPython objects can be pickled. They are just wrappers around C objects, which contain lots of pointers and other stateful stuff. The pickle module doesn't know enough about them to be able to restore their state afterwards.